# Web Api doesn't work when multiple params?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have 2 routes :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default1",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}" 

      );

 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default", 
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My controller looks like :

```
 public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        ...
         public  int GetAll(int id,int id2)
         {
             return 1;
         }

        public Product GetProduct(int id)
        {
          ....
          return item;
        }
     }
```

When I write :`http://localhost:9000/api/products/2`

it matches the second rule and :

[image]

But when I write `http://localhost:9000/api/products/2/3` ( which suppose to match the first rule) :

[image]

**Question**

Where is my mistake ?

nb :

Running `http://localhost:9000/api/products/2?id2=1` does give the right result - but hey ! I made a route specially for this one !

[*(already read this answer - didn't help much)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835074/mvc4-web-api-rest-interface-with-multiple-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have defined the routes above in the RouteConfig rather than the WebApiConfig. Web Api routes should be defined within the WebApiConfig and if you take a look you should find the default route:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

In order to match the url: `api/products/2/3` you will need to add a new route to the WebApiConfig before the existing default route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi2",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{id2}"
);
```

Comment: Yes I read your question. If there is something you are not clear about on my answer then please start a chat and I will be happy to clarify.

Comment: OMG. my apology ! im sorry ! you're right ! (fixing)

Answer (score 0):

It's the way your routes are resolving.

You need to change the order of the routes.

Put `Default` first and `Default1` last since it has more directories to resolve.

Comment: Don't forget to add your defaults parameter/property for Default1 route. This is why you're getting the error

Comment: This is the code : still : error : `public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute...
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default", 
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );

            routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default1",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, id2 = UrlParameter.Optional  } ); }`

Comment: Change `{controller}/` to `api/` in your route, see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supplying an action in your requests.  So to trigger your first route you would need to call:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/products/getall/2/3
```